# Estimating the slope and intercept in python using linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

For an assignment we have been asked to run the code below.

```
# Import numpy
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import numpy.linalg as npl
# Simulate some data as in the end of lecture 4 - but this time of higher dimension
n = 1000
npr.seed(123)
x_1 = npr.uniform(0,10,n)
x_2 = npr.uniform(0,10,n)
x_3 = npr.uniform(0,10,n)
x_4 = npr.uniform(0,10,n)
y = 3 + 2*x_1 - x_2 + 0.5*x_3 - 0.1*x_4 + npr.normal(0,1,n)
# Create a design matrix X with 5 columns, the first of which is all 1 the   subsequent ones are x_1, x_2, etc
X = np.array(([1]*n,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)).T
```

We are asked to use the `inv` function and the standard equation *β = (X<sup>T</sup>X)<sup>-1</sup>X<sup>T</sup>y* to get estimates of the slope and intercept parameters.

We are then asked what values do you get for the intercept and coefficient of `x_1` to 3d.p.?

If anyone could explain this that would be a great help as I am new to Python and would appreciate some guidance.  We are also asked to use the `solve` function to get another estimate of *β*?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? We are not here to do homeworks, sorry. The best I can do is refer you to [numpy's linalg](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html) documentation (as you can find there all you need). Alternatively, you can also check [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/).

Comment: Thank you for the reference I will look at that

Comment: What parts do you understand and what parts do you need help with? This is a Q&A site, so try to ask *specific* questions, rather than 'Can someone explain this, please?' posts. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adding to @das-g comment, if you want our help, we will need to know what do you understand and what you don't. As for the question, it is not clear where are you struggling. Which is what you don't understand? 1) The code you have. 2) The matematical formulation of linear regression. 3) How to do it with numpy/scipy. If you have some more concrete question about any of the previous 3 points, we might be able to help you.

Comment: How do I code the formula for beta?

Comment: @oldtimetrad `inv(transpose(X)*X)*transpose(X)*y`

Comment: Thanks.  I get the error operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,1000) (1000,5) when I run this?

Comment: @oldtimetrad replace `*` by `.dot` as in `transpose(X),dot(X)`. In numpy arrays `*` means element-wise multiplications while `.dot` is matix/vector multiplication.

Comment: I used inv(transpose(X).dot(X)).dot(transpose(X)).dot(y) and this returned

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot